# Laptop Battery and Charger potentially broken?

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power, charger

This is about my roughly 4 years old Asus N551JK, in case it matters.

Whenever the laptop is under heavy load (android studio running, for instance) the battery is acting really weird.
It constantly thinks it's being unplugged and plugged back in. The charging LED goes on and off, and the battery tray icon also displays it as such.
It's gotten the the point where the battery actually discharges entirely after about  2 hours of working on it while it's connected to the wall socket.

The problem is, I don't know if the battery or the charger is to blame.
I am fairly convinced it's not a software issue, so that's ruled out.

Without being plugged in the battery dies after about 30-60 minutes, so I know that it's in a bad state for sure, but not necessarily "broken". It used to last longer than that, though.

The charger is harder to diagnose. It could fail to charge the battery because either of them are broken ... I tested the charger by removing the battery. Laptop ran fine for a bit, then turned off instantly under load. Which leads me to believe that the charger is probably also dead, but I can't say for sure.

- Any advice which of the parts I should try and replace? Particularly unsure about the charger.
- How important is it to find original hardware? the only proper battery I found was like 200€ (and not even in stock!), with a supposedly compatible (same stats, but not the original) battery being 60€.

Comment: MUCH less spendy Stateside: imgur.com/a/quABvBC Much more likely to be the battery assembly than the charger; what's the charger output per a voltmeter?  Maybe it would look good on a voltmeter yet fail under load once connected, but If the charger does not output as specified with no load, it's dead for sure.

Comment: @K7AAY been the to store today and had them check the voltage. It's 18.4V, and it should be 19V. They told me it wasn't too big a deal, though.

Comment: 3% low when not under load can become much worse when the load of the battery is added to the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Lithium Ion batteries are sensitive to temperature, and there is hardware in the battery that may disable charging if the battery gets too hot.  This is a common symptom of a battery that is failing.  When the system is under a higher load and the system temperature increases, the battery will stop charging altogether.  Moreover, if your charger isn't providing enough current to charge the battery and run the laptop under high load, the battery will drain and the system will shut down, even when plugged in.

I agree with K7AAY, this is likely to be a battery problem.